# How to Suppress the iOS [ Small | Medium | Actual Size ] Prompt

Tags: ios, image, react-native, email-attachments

I'm developing a react native app that allows the user to take a photo (or choose one from the gallery) and automatically attaches it to an email. I'm using [react-native-image-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) to select the image, which allows me to optimize the image in terms of

- quality = 0 - 1
- max-height = 1024
- max-width = 1024

The resulting image is exactly what I want, either 1024x768 (landscape) or 768x1024 (portrait) and usually comes in under 100kb.

However, before sending the mail, the user is still presented with an image resize prompt. Since the image is already optimized, I would like to suppress (skip) this prompt. Is there anyway to bypass this prompt?

Furthermore, the prompt is inaccurate. The below image shows the prompt for an image that was pre-optimized to a size of 94kb. To email this full size, fully optimized image, the user must choose "Actual Size". Any other option resizes the image's dimensions and reduces the file size. As you can see, it inaccurately reports that "Actual Size" would be 674kb rather than the actual 94kb. So, if there's no way to suppress the prompt entirely, is it possible to make the size estimates more accurate?

[image]

### UPDATE: An Insight

I noticed this option is not presented when attaching PNGs.

Comment: There is no documented way to avoid the prompt. The best solution to it would be to keep crop / compress. I wonder why it would give the wrong size in the prompt. Can you paste some react-native code to show how you pick the image and attach it to the email?

Comment: Hi @li8, thanks for your reply. I'm not sure what you mean by "keep crop / compress" being the best solution. As for the code, I didn't include it because I'm not sure it would be very insightful, but a working demo app is on my github. You can find the code you requested here https://github.com/geirman/react-native-photo-emailer/blob/master/app/root.js